# If I want to travel to Brazil, can I get by with English?

Tags: brazil, language-barrier, languages, english-language

I do not speak Portuguese, and only enough Spanish not to starve. English is my second language, but my first, Dutch, will not be very useful.
Will people in Brazil be able to communicate with me?

I am willing to go down to a kind of sign language combined with single words but at times you need someone to translate.
So will there be someone speaking English in every touristy location as well as in many towns and villages off the beaten track?

Comment: [Try this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate).

Comment: You may not understand them, but many of them will understand your Spanish.  I have had conversations with Brazilians where I spoke Spanish and they spoke Portuguese.

Comment: During my trip to Sao Paolo, I realized that people understand very little other than Portuguese (the Brazilian dialect). Very touristy places understand a little, but usually using a combination of sign-language, bits-n-pieces of Portuguese you can make do. There are many sites that have handy tourist-friendly phrasebooks that you can print-out. Also if you have an android phone, install Google Translate, with Brazilian Portuguese and English/Dutch, along with Text-To-Speech database, for offline use (s.t. you can use it even without internet connection).

Comment: @icarus74 can you please make that into an answer? Maybe limited geographic spread but very useful extra information.

Comment: Related question: [Communicating in English or basic Portuguese in Brazil](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53379/29220)

Comment: If you are Dutch then English is like a first language (source : my never ending astonishment about the mastering of English by Dutchmen.  I once had a chat with a tractor driver who sounded like he was straight from BBC)

Comment: @WoJ, thanks for the compliment but it took me quite a while to get to fluent level in English and I am still learning. Many Dutch do much less good, the odd one that is almost native level you meet may hide a lot who are way less good.

Comment: @Willeke: my lovely stay at the University of Groningen (and trips in the countryside) gave a totally different impression :) Gelukkig nieuwjaar!

Comment: @WoJ, Happy New Year,  half the Dutch people I work with do not speak across the border more than to order food/beer, not enough English for a conversation. And I have reason to know as we regularly have people working there who do not (yet) speak Dutch, so English is quite commonly used with them, for those that can. Helps newcomers to learn Dutch fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am living in Brazil (Rio Grande do Norte) and I can tell you from experience that tourist staff will not be able to understand anything beyond the most basic phrases unless this is a specialty of your hotel or resort.

You'll probably be able to get " Cardapio em ingles" (english menu) at almost anywhere though, with the items numbered and more or less translated understandably, the prices may well not be listed or even different than the other menu.

Im in no way connected to this company, but CVC viagems is a really well known travel agent franchise who would be able to arrange payment/transit/orientations for you in the cities and major resort areas.

Answer (score 11):

Yes not many Brazilians speak the English language especially outside Rio de Janeiro or Sao Paulo.

Try to learn as much Portuguese as you can before visiting there. You can also take the help of translator apps, phrasebooks and Youtube to learn basic stuff in Portuguese.

> *English* is not widely spoken except in some touristy areas. Don't
>   expect bus or taxi drivers to understand English, so it may be a good
>   idea to write down the address you are heading to before getting the
>   cab. In most big and luxurious hotels, it is very likely that the taxi
>   fleet will speak some English. If you are really in need of talking in
>   English, you should look for the younger people (-30 years), because
>   they, generally, have a higher knowledge of the language and will be
>   eager to help you and exercise their English. 
>        [(Source)](http://wikitravel.org/en/Brazil)

Answer (score 5):

English is hardly spoken in Brazil.  Your hotel receptionist in Rio may well speak English, but very few others will. Even in Ipanema -- one of the most popular parts of Rio for international tourists --English is not spoken.